# Automating business process - logging in and downloading a file asp.net application

Tags: process, automation, watin, web-scraping

I have a task to automate a business process. The process must go to a website, log in, click on a couple of links and choose some options in dropdown boxes and download a file.

I also want to put this process on a Windows 2003 server as a scheduled task.

What would be the best way to solve this problem? I was looking around at WaTin, and it seems to do the job, but it seems like it is more for testing. I'm also not sure how it would work with Windows Scheduled tasks because they run in the background and i'm not sure how it would go with calling up another process (ie or firefox) and manipulating that window. Is this possible?

Otherwise any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WatiN can definitely do what you want, however I would not recommend it running in that manner. Watin works best when running with the browser open and in full view with a logged in user account.